# I am unable to connect to wifi network, using a 'Dell Inspiron 3521' with Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I am unable to connect to wifi network in my Dell Inspiron 3521 with Ubuntu 12.04, even though my Internet cable connection (LAN) is working just fine.

I have installed 'broadcom STA' and its required softwares, but I am not able to connect to wifi network. Also there are no results when I run following command, so I am unable to identify the chipset:

```
lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4
```

- Can you help me identify the chipset and also resolve the wifi problem?

Comment: Please show us: lspci -nn | grep 0280 Thanks.

Comment: This is the output of lspci -nn | grep 0280   phani@phani-Inspiron-3521:~$  lspci -nn | grep 0280
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)

Answer (score 0):

Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection. Open a terminal and run:

```
uname -r
```

Is your kernel version annotated '-pae'? If so, please do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.10-precise-generic-pae
```

If not, do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.10-precise-generic
```

Detach the ethernet and do:

```
sudo modprobe ath9k
```

Your wireless should now be working.